# sklearn-LinearRegression:could not convert string to float: '{}'

Tags: python, linear-regression

I am training my model using linear regression
`lin_reg_model.fit(X_train,Y_train)`
but this error is coming

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> ----> 1 lin_reg_model.fit(X_train,Y_train)
>
> 4 frames /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py
> in **array**(self, dtype)    1991     1992     def **array**(self,
> dtype: NpDtype | None = None) -> np.ndarray:
> -> 1993         return np.asarray(self._values, dtype=dtype)    1994     1995     def **array_wrap**(
>
> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '{}'
> Please help

Comment: Can you show a piece of code? That would help :)

Comment: X = robot_dataset.drop(['Article ID','Article Date'],axis=1)
Y = robot_dataset['Article Date'] print(X)  print(Y)    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.1, random_state=2) lin_reg_model = LinearRegression()